# Simultaneous fitting to multiple data sets with multiple variables and some common parameters

Tags: fitting

I am trying to fit two data sets to a function model described below which share a few common parameters. Say I have two functions with some common parameter(s)

```
f[x_,y_]:= a*Exp[-x]*Sin[b*y] + c
g[x_,y_]:= d*Exp[-x]*Sin[b*y] + c
```

I generated two model data sets using a functional form similar to the ones above and tried to fit the data using `NonlinearModelFit`. But `NonlinearModelFit` fails to converge within the prescribed iterations and confidence interval.

I tried checking the threads ([Combined fitting via NonlinearModelFit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15905/combined-fitting-via-nonlinearmodelfit) or http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Sep/msg00555.html or http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/135933) on similar discussions but could not solve my problem. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Arijit.

Comment: Could you also add the code you tried for fitting the data using `NonlinearModelFit`. Did you try to use good starting values for the fit?