# How I can use FindFit to simultaneously fit two data sets to two equations having shared parameters?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting

I think that `FindFit` package with the method `Nminimize` yields global minimum if initial values of adjustable parameters are chosen properly with some constraints. I did use it to fit one data set to one formula but I wonder if one can hint to me how I can make a simultaneous fit to two different data sets and two different equations with some shared parameters.

Comment: Please see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63719/134).

Comment: I tried two different simple polynomial equations with some common parameters to fit simultaneously  two different sets of home-made data using both FindFit and NonLinearModelFit packages. Output values of common parameters were same and fits were good. But this was not the case when I have chosen more complex equations and the outcome oarameters and fits were bad and inconsistent. This will be a useless if one wants to fit simultaneously equations of real and imaginary parts of dielectric constant to their highly different measured data. This is a challange for both physicits and others !!!!!

Comment: When attempting to fit different data sets with some common parameters one has to apply the appropriate weight during the fitting process. See [Simultaneous fit to three datasets with measurement errors using different models but same parameters](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/153303/simultaneous-fit-to-three-datasets-with-measurement-errors-using-different-model/153313#153313) for an example.