# Simultaneous plotting

Tags: fitting, complex

For my experiment, I have to simultaneously fit the real part and imaginary part of cavity reflection data which is given [here](http://pastebin.com/vpqzFWte)

column 1: frequency,
column 2: reflection magnitude,
column 3: phase

I followed the similar approach which is shown by one of the user Rob Sewell,[here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/866/simultaneously-fitting-multiple-datasets)

```
da1 = Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2]]*Cos[data[[All, 3]]]}];
da2 = Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], (data[[All, 2]]*
  Sin[data[[All, 3]]])}];
Repart[x_, y_, f_, f0_, A_] := A + (x y - 4 (f - f0)^2)/(4 (f - f0)^2 + y^2);
Impart[x_, y_, f_, f0_, B_] := B + ((f - f0) (x + y))/((f - f0)^2 + x^2);
Clear[A, B, x, y, f, f0, set]
dat = Join[da1 /. {x_, y_} -> {1, x, y}, da2 /. {x_, y_} -> {2, x, y}];
fitmodel[set_, x_, y_, f_, f0_, A_, B_] := 
Which[set == 1, Evaluate@Repart[x, y, f, f0, A], set == 2, 
Evaluate@Impart[x, y, f, f0, B]]
fit = NonlinearModelFit[dat,fitmodel[set, x, y, f, f0], {{x, 0.0001}, 
{y,0.0001}, {f0, 10.10},A, B}, {f, set}, MaxIterations -> Infinity];
fitparams = fit["BestFitParameters"]
```

The code always gives out error, Am I missing something here?I have already checked real part and imaginary part separately , that works perfectly fine; but I need to simultaneously plot this,

A complex plot might also helps , I guess.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: "NonlinearModelFit::nrlnum" .  By the way there was a mistake I made in the code when I copied to this page, Please have a look at it again(I have edited the code once again)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated with new model equations from OP**

Simultaneous `NonlinearModelFit[]`

```
da1 = Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2]]*Cos[data[[All, 3]]]}];
da2 = Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], (data[[All, 2]]*Sin[data[[All, 3]]])}];

r[f_] := A - (x y - 4 (f - f0)^2)/(4 (f - f0)^2 + y^2);
i[f_] := B + (2*(f - f0) (x + y))/((4 (f - f0)^2 + y^2));

Clear[A, B, x, y, f, f0, index]

(*Prepend 1 to data for i,2 to data for r*)
allData = Join[{1, Sequence @@ #} & /@ da1, {2, Sequence @@ #} & /@ da2];

myF[index_, f_] := KroneckerDelta[index - 1] i[f] + KroneckerDelta[index - 2] r[f]

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[allData, myF[index, f], 
      {{x, 0.001}, {y, 0.001}, {f0, 10.10}, {A, 1.5}, {B, 0.02}}, 
      {index, f}, MaxIterations -> 1000];

Show[ListPlot[{da1, da2}], Plot[{nlm[1, f], nlm[2, f]}, {f, 10.0, 10.2}]]

fitparams = nlm["BestFitParameters"]
```

> {x -> -0.00652867, y -> 0.00777036, f0 -> 10.1007, A -> -0.534572,   B
>   -> -0.0234361}

[image]

[Reference](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15905/combined-fitting-via-nonlinearmodelfit/15913#15913)

Comment: Sorry, I have added the real part and imaginary part as same when I defined the function, , Could you check once again please

Comment: Dear Young, what you have shown is not simulatenous fitting, these are separate fitting

Comment: This is not what I want

Comment: Dear Young,Thanks for the plot, but I am not very sure about this answer cause  y must be a positive real number since it is essentially the  bandwidth  for the Lorentzian  curve (Real part)

Comment: @TM90 could the model equations be wrong? does Pi need to be in there somewhere?

Comment: @TM90 Did this help? Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: @ Young, Thanks for your amazing help, Yes it helped a lot

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Young for the answers, The problem was simple , there was a slight modification in the equation, which is give below

```
i[f_] := A - (x y - 4 (f - f0)^2)/(4 (f - f0)^2 + y^2);
r[f_] := B + (2*(f - f0) (x + y))/((4 (f - f0)^2 + y^2));
```

[image]

and as Evans mentioned, the Parametric plot will be the following

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is an illustrated comment to Young's answer, but you can plot in the Re/Im plane using the following:

```
Show[
 ListPlot[
  Transpose@{Last /@ da1, Last /@ da2}
  , Joined -> True
  , AxesLabel -> {"Re", "Im"}
  ]
 ,
 ParametricPlot[
  {nlm[1, f], nlm[2, f]}
  , {f, Min@(First /@ da1), Max@(First /@ da1)}
  , PlotStyle -> Red
  ]
 , PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Evans for the plot