# Simultaneous fitting of polynomial parameters to data

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, data

I have two following data-sets:

```
data1={{386.10999999999996`, 2.99831`}, {385.07`, 4.26322`}, {384.03`, 
   5.08508`}, {383.12`, 5.58428`}, {382.08`, 
   6.13079`}, {381.03999999999996`, 6.53994`}, {380.`, 
   6.82545`}, {378.96`, 7.00631`}, {378.44`, 
   7.06699`}, {377.91999999999996`, 7.23226`}, {377.4`, 
   7.43319`}, {376.88`, 7.39476`}, {376.35999999999996`, 
   7.59252`}, {375.96999999999997`, 7.852`}, {375.84`, 
   7.84731`}, {375.58`, 7.96505`}, {375.32`, 8.05784`}, {375.19`, 
   8.16459`}, {375.05999999999995`, 8.16023`}, {374.92999999999995`, 
   8.09303`}, {374.92999999999995`, 8.1093`}, {374.79999999999995`, 
   8.16085`}, {374.66999999999996`, 8.29507`}, {374.53999999999996`, 
   8.29715`}, {374.40999999999997`, 8.20119`}};
data2={{386.12638`, 1.16966`}, {385.10276`, 1.44312`}, {384.07914`, 
   1.55275`}, {383.05552`, 1.67674`}, {382.03189999999995`, 
   1.70782`}, {381.00827999999996`, 1.75575`}, {379.98465999999996`, 
   1.8141`}, {378.96103999999997`, 2.04406`}, {377.93742`, 
   2.14611`}, {377.42561`, 2.24514`}, {376.9138`, 
   2.49293`}, {376.40198999999996`, 2.5167`}, {375.99249`, 
   2.52265`}, {375.78774`, 2.55287`}, {375.58312`, 
   2.51717`}, {375.37836999999996`, 2.49299`}, {375.17361999999997`, 
   2.54704`}, {375.07131`, 2.60758`}, {374.96887`, 
   2.53487`}, {374.86656`, 2.65357`}, {374.76412`, 
   2.6157`}, {374.66180999999995`, 2.71675`}, {374.50827999999996`, 
   2.63708`}, {374.45705999999996`, 2.75287`}, {374.35474999999997`, 
   2.81088`}};
```

How can I fit two polynomials simulatneously (below, $A$ intentionally are the same)?
$$F(x)=(4A+2B)x^2$$
$$G(x)=4Ax^2$$

When I try to employ solution proposed in [Combined fitting via NonlinearModelFit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15905/combined-fitting-via-nonlinearmodelfit)

```
allData =  Join[{1, Sequence @@ #} & /@ data1, {2, Sequence @@ #} & /@ data2];
f[x_]:= (4A+2B)*x^2
g[x_]:= 4A*x^2
myF[index_, x_] :=  KroneckerDelta[index - 1] f[x] + KroneckerDelta[index - 2] g[x]

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[allData, myF[index, x], {A, B}, {index, x}];

Show[ListPlot[{data1, data2}],  Plot[{nlm[1, x], nlm[2, x]}, {x, 374, 387}]]
```

as a result I do not get any fit (no fit is plotted).

Comment: A web search for `mathematica stackexchange simultaneous fit` will turn up several relevant hits.

Comment: However, I could not find relevant (similar) cases that I could implement.

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. You need to explain in which way your problem is different from the other solutions available, otherwise your question will be closed as a [duplicate](https://wolfr.am/wbjeaXyW),

Comment: You have multiple typos.  You use `A` and `B` in the function definitions and then `a` and `b` in `NonlinearModelFit`.  And the range in the `Plot` is `{x, 1, 25}` when it should be something closer to the observed data:  `{x, 374, 387}`.  Once those typos are fixed, things run but you get an extremely poor fit.

Comment: @JimB I have made a revision you have suggested but still I do not get a reliable output (no fit is shown).

Comment: Your revised code works fine for me on Mathematica 10.4 (Windows 10).  What version and operating system are you using?

Comment: @JimB Mathematica 11.3 (Windows 10)

Comment: Fixed, works fine

Comment: By the way, why in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15905/combined-fitting-via-nonlinearmodelfit Kronecker's deltas are used?